# PhoneGap Android - Playing Local Videos

Tags: android, html, video, cordova

Is it possible to play videos on Android stored in the www folder in PhoneGap using the HTML5 video tag?

Answer (score 0):

[Phonegap HTML5 Video Made easy](http://www.html5videoplayer.net/phonegap-html5-video.html) ,yes it is possible to play the video using phone-gap android,html5

[VideoPlayer](https://github.com/macdonst/VideoPlayer)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to play localVideo Files (added in your project assets folder) you can use [FILE OPENER PLUGIN](https://github.com/michalzubkowicz/FileOpener/tree/cordova-2.8.0)
i was getting so may problems to play files using  or  or  [Video Player Plugin](https://github.com/macdonst/VideoPlayer) but i successfully played all videos.Try to use this plugin

[FILE OPENER PLUGIN](https://github.com/michalzubkowicz/FileOpener/tree/cordova-2.8.0)

Answer (score 0):

This might not the best answer. But for those who still couldn't get it done, you can use a separate Android activity to do that. You can call DroidGap class methods from JavaScript. But, this method will violate the cross platform rule. Since I cannot explain every step in here, please refer this [link](http://tiriboy.blogspot.com/2014/08/phonegap-playing-local-video.html).